# c# asp.net DateTime cached

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, datetime

I've got a field on a class that should set the current date correctly:

```
private static DateTime Today = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
```

And then I'm performing different logic based on the day.
The problem is that it works locally but it won't work on the live server.
So for example if the date is the 5th then the logic of the 4th will be performed, unless I touch the web.config or I update the dlls. So I assume it is a cache problem, but why? I'm not caching the date at all.
I did not use the DateTime.Today because I thought that was the problem...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `DateTime.Today`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a `static` field.

It is initialized once per AppDomain.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you want to do, but for me it looks like that you want the current Day without the time. You can get this using

```
DateTime.Now.Date
```

Answer (score 1):

> I did not use the DateTime.Today because I thought that was the problem...

What made you think that?

---

**[DateTime.Today Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx)**

> Type: System.DateTime
>   An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00.

---

`Today` is a static variable and is set only once per domain